# $indexOfArray searching by object property inside array element mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

lets say I have de below document:

```
{
 _id: ObjectId("5c86b93028bbb5001063782b"),
 events: [
  {
   eventName: event1
   data: {
    person: {
     name: 'Jhon'
    }
   }
  },
  {
   eventName: event2
   data: {
    person: {
     name: 'Alex'
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to get the event BEFORE events.data.person.name: "alex", in this case event1

I tried to use $arrayElementAt and $indexOfArray, but I am having trouble to filter $indexOfArray in the object person.name inside the element array, I can only filter like below:

```
$project:{
 event: {
  $arrayElemAt: [
    "$events", 
    { 
      $subtract: [
        { 
          $indexOfArray: [
            "$events.name",
            'event2'
          ]
        }, 
        1, 
      ]
    }
  ],
}
}
```

this doesn't work

```
$project:{
 event: {
  $arrayElemAt: [
    "$events", 
    { 
      $subtract: [
        { 
          $indexOfArray: [
            "$events.data.person.name",
            'Alex'
          ]
        }, 
        1, 
      ]
    }
  ],
}
}
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score -1):

I solved by doing a map first with a $eq searching by my value, then a new array is created with a bunch of falses, and a true on my index I want, so now I filtered by searching the true value

Comment: Can you explain with example what you did? From what you wrote it's very unclear where you applied the map...